# Page not found while accessing website content

Tags: multi-sites

I set up a Drupal 9.2.1 site, which working fine until I set it up as multi-site.

- I have the master site in the main directory for Xampp (C:\xampp\htdocs) in the *master.com* directory
- I created six multi-sites in *C:\xampp\htdocs\master.com\sites* with the following sub-directories: *site1.com*, *site2.com*, *site3.com*, *site4.com*, *site5.com*, *site6.com*
- I updated the the *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc* file

  ```
  127.0.0.1  localhost
  127.0.0.1  master.com
  127.0.0.1  site1.com
  127.0.0.1  site2.com
  127.0.0.1  site3.com
  127.0.0.1  site4.com
  127.0.0.1  site5.com
  127.0.0.1  site6.com
  ```
- I updated the *C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf* file

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName master.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site1.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/master.com"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site2.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/master.com"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site3.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/master.com"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site4.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/master.com"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site5.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/master.com"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site6.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/master.com"
  </VirtualHost>
  ```
- I updated the *C:\xampp\htdocs\SpeakFreely.com\sites\sites.php* file

  ```php
  $sites['site1.com'] = 'site1.com';
  $sites['site2.com'] ='site2.com';
  $sites['site3.com'] ='site3.com';
  $sites['site4.com'] ='site4.com';
  $sites['site5.com']='site5.com';
  $sites['site6.com'] ='site6.com';
  ```

I cannot access the site content; I always get a 404 error. The other six sites work fine.

website hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: Can you check that

1. master.com is pointing to drupal webroot, from

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName master.com
   DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
</VirtualHost>

it appears the master.com is not pointing to drupal webroot.

Secondly do you have default site folder along with site1.com, site2.com since you do not have master.com folder for master I assume master.com should be pointing to default site.

Comment: @arpitr yes I have the default directory along with site1.com,site2.com.I updated the question with the site hierarchy. how I make the master point to Webroot in this case ?